# Как изменить фон сайта через JS?

Tags: javascript, css

Попробовал так:

```
document.body.style.background = 
        'url(http://media.rockstargames.com/rockstargames/img/global/downloads/wallpapers/games/v-igg2-1920x1080.jpg)';
```

Но не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы чуть чуть не угадали :)

`document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://media.rockstargames.com/rockstargames/img/global/downloads/wallpapers/games/v-igg2-1920x1080.jpg)';`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: Это значит на вашей html странице нет `<body>` ... Или вы это делаете не в браузере. Или вы это делаете слишком рано, до того как body загрузилось

Comment: @Mike напрасно вы насчет "чуть-чуть". С `.background` тоже вполне работает: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/342rbLgk/). Проблема автора и его магическое "не работает", скорее всего, в чём-то из того, что вы описали в комментарии.

Comment: Свойство `background` - общее сво-во, оно тоже может ссылаться на изображение, если в значении указать `url()`
[пруф](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background)

Answer (score 2):

Возможно ваша проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь изменить background до полной загрузки страницы.

Попробуйте следующее:

js

```
var ReplaceBackground = function() {
   document.body.style.background = 'url(http://media.rockstargames.com/rockstargames/img/global/downloads/wallpapers/games/v-igg2-1920x1080.jpg)';
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ReplaceBackground);
```